# CURL - add content to an existing file using one request

Tags: curl, ftp

after searching info about curl on google , I think it's not possible, but I'll ask anyway:

Is is possible to add content to a file using curl without changing its original content (using only one curl request!).

For instance, I have a simple txt file:
"hello this is test"

and I would want to add another line to the file:
"hello this is test
 and I have a second line!"

currently my curl looks like this (it overwrite my file):

```
curl THE_FTP_ADRESS -X PUT -1 -v --disable-epsv --ftp-skip-pasv-ip --ftp-ssl-ccc -u MYUSR:PASS --upload-file MY_FILE_ADRESS
```

I think it's possible to fetch the file from the ftp server, then add up the part I want to add and overwrite it on the ftp server, but I want to know if there's a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

curl has [a `--append` option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-a) to append to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Nop...

This is a FTP class option:

`-a`, `--append`: (FTP/SFTP) When used in an upload, this makes curl append to the target file instead of overwriting it. If the remote file doesn't exist, it will be created. Note that this flag is ignored by some SFTP servers (including OpenSSH).